# Как передать файл из Model в JS для обработки?

Tags: javascript, html, json, django

Есть модель в **Models**:

```
class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
```

Используемый файл в поле `file` имеет тип JSON. Необходимо извлечь из него данные для построения сцены. Вот скрипт со страницы, где будет строиться сцена, сейчас просто вывод одного из значений. Идёт обращение по ключу `particles` к нулевому элементу массива его значений, который является словарём, из него извлекаются все значения и вносятся в массив `vl`. В конце, для теста, вывод значения из `vl`.

**Скрипт с detail.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function () {
        var a = JSON.parse({{ post.file.url }});
        var vl = [];
        var b = a["particles"];
        var c = b[0];
        var p = c.values();
        for (var i=0; i<p.length; i++){
            vl.append(p[i]);
        }
        alert(vl[0]);
    });
```

**Скрипт на странице не выполняется. Ошибка из консоли браузера:**
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`

**Строка с ошибкой:**
`var a = JSON.parse({{ post.file.url }});`

**Переход на страницу со скриптом:**

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
<li><a href="{% url 'landings:detail' post.id %}" title="Пост файл">{{ post.title }}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls:**

```
app_name = 'landings'    
url(r'^landing/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

**views:**

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'landing/detail.html', {'post': post})

def landing(request):
    form = PostForm()
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'landing/landing.html', locals(), {'form': form})
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашёл сам. Изменить модель, добавив:

```
def display_file(self):
    l = open(self.file.path, mode="r")
    c = json.load(l)
    return c
```

В скрипт передавать **post.display_file**.
И в html отключить экранирование

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% endautoescape %}
```